# Pandas explode dictionary to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    Name                                    Sub_Marks
0    Tom  {'Maths': 30, 'English': 40, 'Science': 35}
1  Harry  {'Maths': 35, 'English': 30, 'Science': 25}
2   Nick  {'Maths': 32, 'English': 23, 'Science': 20}
```

I need to explode the dictionary into multiple rows. E.g.

```
    Name  Subject  Marks
0    Tom    Maths     30
1    Tom  English     40
2    Tom  Science     35
3  Harry    Maths     35
4  Harry  English     30
5  Harry  Science     25
6   Nick    Maths     32
7   Nick  English     23
8   Nick  Science     20
```

I know we can explode list in dataframe. Is there any way to do it with dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can create a list of tuples of `Name`, `Marks` and `Subjects` by iterating over the values of dataframe inside a list comprehension, then we can create a new dataframe from this list of tuples

```
out = pd.DataFrame([(n, k, v) for (n, d) in df.values for k, v in d.items()])
out.columns = ['Name', 'Subject', 'Marks']
```

Alternative `pandas` based approach

```
m = pd.DataFrame([*df['Sub_Marks']], df.index).stack()\
      .rename_axis([None,'Subject']).reset_index(1, name='Marks')

out = df[['Name']].join(m)
```

---

```
>>> out

    Name  Subject  Marks
0    Tom    Maths     30
1    Tom  English     40
2    Tom  Science     35
3  Harry    Maths     35
4  Harry  English     30
5  Harry  Science     25
6   Nick    Maths     32
7   Nick  English     23
8   Nick  Science     20
```

Comment: Wow. I like your pandas solution. That unpacking was clever.
You have my upvote.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening in the `*df['Sub_Marks']` part?

Comment: `*` is used here to unpack the column `Sub_Marks` as a `list`, so instead of using `[*df['Sub_Marks']]` you can also use `list(df['Sub_Marks'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can extract only the values from the `dictionaries` and then expand it to multiple columns like this:

```
data = {'Name' : ['Tom', "Harry", "Nick"], "Sub_Marks" : [{'Maths': 30, 'English': 40, 'Science': 35},{'Maths': 35, 'English': 42, 'Science': 31},{'Maths': 20, 'English': 14, 'Science': 65}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['Maths','English', 'Science']] = df['Sub_Marks'].apply(pd.Series)
df.drop(columns=['Sub_Marks'], inplace=True)
df = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Name', 'Subject', 'Marks']
```

Comment: No need to use `apply` + `dict.values`, creating a new dataframe from list of dictionary automatically takes care of that ;)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Oh. I am not sure if it does because it still shows me a dict in the column. But `apply(pd.Series)` works too.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list(df['Sub_Marks']))` will expand list of dictionaries into a dataframe where the column names in this frame corresponds to all the unique keys present in the list of dictionaries, generally you should avoid using `apply` + `pd.Series` because that is more computationally expensive operation :)

Comment: Ahh I got it know. I think I misunderstood earlier. Also, didn't know `apply` + `pd.Series` being computationally expensive. Thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pd.Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to 'explode' the dictionary into columns and then use [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to transform the columns into `Subject` and `Marks` columns, as follows:

```
(df.drop(columns='Sub_Marks')
   .join(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Sub_Marks']), axis=1))
   .melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=['Maths', 'English', 'Science'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Marks')
   .sort_values('Name')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can also use `pd.DataFrame()` together with `to_list()` to 'explode' the dictionary:

```
(df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Sub_Marks').to_list()))
   .melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=['Maths', 'English', 'Science'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Marks')
   .sort_values('Name')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Subject  Marks
0  Harry    Maths     35
1  Harry  English     30
2  Harry  Science     25
3   Nick    Maths     32
4   Nick  English     23
5   Nick  Science     20
6    Tom    Maths     30
7    Tom  English     40
8    Tom  Science     35
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method via `explode`  -

```
df['Marks'] = df['Sub_Marks'].apply(lambda x: x.values())
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode).rename(columns = {'Sub_Marks': 'Subject'})
```

You might wanna use `ast.literal_eval` first (if above method doesn't work) -

```
import ast
df['Sub_Marks'] = df['Sub_Marks'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```